# 3 volt string led light adapting to 5v usb charger source

Tags: led

[image]

I would like to cut off the batteries, and light these 10 led string light with 5v usb. I dont know how much current flows throught them, and dont know what resistor should I use.  Please help. Im a newbie.

Comment: Can you measure how much current is being drawn from the batteries?

Comment: unfortunately I dont have a multimeter device.

Comment: I found information on the box of the ledstring. It says: 3V/80ma    0.3W

Comment: Start with a higher resistor and reduce until a comparable brightness is obtained, or preferably a little dimmer to avoid stressing things.   If you setup with some clip leads you could keep switching back and forth between the new solution and the original batteries to compare.  Make sure the resistor is not getting warm to the touch, if it is use a physically larger package.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no electronics here - just a 3V battery source and a switch. So those white LEDs are all wired in parallel. 3V is applied to every LED.

If you were to substitute a 5V source, the series resistor would have to drop about 2V. Even with 10 mA flowing, you get some light. 80 mA would be quite bright.

- 10 mA would require a 200 ohm resistor in series
- 80 mA would require a 25 ohm resistor in series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhPaaD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any resistor between 25 ohms and 200 ohms would be appropriate - the smaller value giving more light.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to toss battery or use it occasional when not connected to USB? 3V/80mA= 37.5 Ohms effective load at 3V.  You can do both.

- to get same brightness use 2V drop/80mA= 25 Ohms in series with 5V since both share same current. Higher R reduces current and brightness both.
- While 3V drops slightly since Internal resistance of 4? LEDs will be 16/4=4 Ohms for these types.

Get a DMM in future. < $10

Comment: thank you for the most useful advice I appreciate it.